# Selenium cannot click on input button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am testing the website [BookDepository](https://www.bookdepository.com) for a course project. I decided to make a utility test case for the Login process, which I could use for other test cases instead of signing in every time. However, the `click` command for the `Sign In` input doesn't seem to work. All test cases pass but the login process does not occur. The button isn't really clicked (or so it seems). Selenium IDE correctly identifies the input button by its id. Replacing the target expression with `XPath`/`CSS` alternatives doesn't work. `pause` at the end of the test doesn't work either. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I noticed that if I select "Play from here" on the faulty `click` command, the click does occur.

Comment: could you share your code here to make it easier to debug?

Comment: @Daniel If answer helped you to solve/fix your issue, please do accept the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. Recording the test again didn't resolve the problem. I cannot use the code, because I use Selenium IDE, which doesn't support tests, written in code. But I upvoted your answer, because you put effort and tried helping me though. I am grateful for it.

Answer (score 2):

**Working solution :**

- I can perform click on Sign In button have not face any challenge with ID - `signInSubmit`
- Example :

> element=driver.find_element(By.ID,"signInSubmit") element.click()

Comment: My first selector was also by ID but it didn't work in Selenium IDE. Does this mean Selenium IDE is causing the problem and if I write it in code, I will avoid it?

Comment: No. @DanielHalachev But are you facing same issue with every click() you performed? If yes then definitely need to double check the setup locally otherwise go ahead your infra is ready

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking the Sign In button using JavaScript executor.

```
WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", signInButton);
```

If that doesn't work you can try adding wait:

1. Implicit Wait: Add a short implicit wait of 2-3 seconds before clicking the Sign In button to ensure the page is loaded and the element is clickable.
2. Explicit Wait: Use an explicit wait for the presence of the Sign In button and then click it. This would wait for the specified amount of time until the element is clickable.